# How do I formulate a staircase function in PuLP constraint

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pulp

I am trying to use PuLP package to solve my optimisation model. But I am having a hard time converting the staircase function in my math formula to PuLP constraint
Here's the simplified problem.

```
from pulp import *
# declaration of problem
linearProblem = LpProblem("Minimise",LpMinimize)

# some predefined info
c_oi = {(1,1):1,(1,2):1,(1,3):0,(1,4):0,(2,1):1,(2,2):0,(2,3):1,(2,4):0,(3,1):1,(3,2):0,(3,3):0,(3,4):1}
x_ik_list = ['(1, 1)', '(1, 2)', '(2, 1)', '(2, 2)','(3, 1)', '(3, 2)', '(4, 1)', '(4, 2)']
index1 = [1,2,3,4]
index2 = [1,2]
index3 = [1,2,3]
ID_list = [123,124,9776,39289]

# decision var
x_ik_var = pulp.LpVariable.dict("x",x_ik_list,cat='Binary')
S_i = pulp.LpVariable.dict("S",index1,lowBound=0, upBound=None,cat='Integer')

# obj
linearProblem += lpSum([c_oi[(o,i)]*S_i[i] for i in index1 for o in index3])
```

The constraint is a staircase function about decision variable S_i, The logic is like below

```
S_i[i] = 0 if the abs(ID_list[i]*x_ik[str((i,k))]-ID_list[j]*x_ik[str((j,k))]) < 10 and = 1 otherwise (i,j is in index1, k is in index2)
```

Is there a way to input the staircase function as a constraint in PuLP. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: the abs can be modeled with 2 constraints: 1) a >= x - y, and 2) a >= y - x

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm wondering how do you input a staircase (step) function into PuLP constraint like the example above, S_i = 0 (if ...) and S_i = 1 (if ...). And the if contains another decision variable like above. Could you please suggest? thanks

Comment: It looks like for each i you will have  rows for each j and k.  do you you want your S_i[i] = 0 if  abs(...... ) < 10 for all j and k, or for any j and k, or should there be a sum in there?

Comment: generally, the formula for each segment takes the form of: binary_flag * big_num >= expression.   so the binary_flag will be 0 if the expression is <= 0 and 1 otherwise

Comment: Yes, it is for any i, j in index 1 and any k in index 2 and i != j. Hence the if is saying that as long as my binary variable x_ik is 1 and the ID  number difference is less or equal to ten, i should have S_i as 1. And for higher ID number difference, S_i should be 0.
I still don't know how do I form such logic in  PuLP as a constraint. Could you please show me some code if possible. Thanks!